# How to prevent form validation when you go back in the multipage form? STRUTS 1

Tags: validation, struts-1

How to prevent form validation when you go back in the multipage form? I have a validation in the XML and I want it to be checked when you click "next" (it works) and that it doesn't work when you click back(in my case it's cancel button). Unfortunately in my case validation happens in both cases..... any ideas? I'd be grateful:)

Comment: Sorry to ask, how is this related to Struts 1.x at all?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Because it's the S1 validation that's firing?

Comment: Oh! I understand the OP now. He has a validation XML page that he created. He wants that the validation should not fire when the back button is clicked. The question didn't make sense at first (I thought the OP validated an XML file).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of solving this issue, it's called: Preventing double submission.

Struts 1.x allows this by saving a token after an action is called. The 3 methods that you need to look at are from the Struts 1.x [`Action`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html) class:

- `resetToken`
- `isTokenValid`
- `saveToken`

Thus, on your action method, you will have to do a token validation check to see if this action was executed before. It it hasn't been executed, continue with your action.

Below is an example on how the validation should be done:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ActionForward forward = null;

    boolean valid = isTokenValid(request);
    if (!valid) {
        //We HAVE NOT yet ran this action, let's execute our action.
        //TODO: Complete the rest of the code.

        //Map my forward
        forward = .....;

        //Finally, save this action for further execution.
        saveToken(request);
    } else {
        //Forward, as usual....?
        forward = .....;
    }

    return forward;
}
```

There is a [tutorial online](http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/optional/struts/1.0.1/reference/html/ch10.html) that explains the whole concept of token session to prevent double (form) submission.